# Subspaces and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In a vector space $P_3$ of all real polynomials, where:

$$H = \{p(t)=a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + a_3t^3 \ \ | \ \ a_0 + a_2 = 0\ \  \text{and}\ \ \ a_1 + a_3 = 0\}$$

How do I show that $H$ is a subspace of $P_3$?

Comment: Welcome to Math. SE! It's always important show what you have tried so far. 

[Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on how to use MathJax and Latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that

$1) \ \ 0 \in H$;

$2) \ \  p(t),q(t) \in H \implies p(t) + q(t) \in H$;

$3) \ \ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p(t) \in H \implies \alpha p(t) \in H$

Hint for $(2)$:

$$p(t) + q(t) = (a_0 + b_0) +(a_1 + b_1)t + (a_2 + b_2)t^2 + (a_3 + b_3)t^3$$

what can you tell of $(a_0 + b_0 + a_1 + b_1) = (a _ 0 + a_1) + (b_0 + b_1) = \cdots$?

Comment: If you have any questions feel free to ask.